# How to filter out SQL results using Like and Not like at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-like

I've got the following text data I'd like to filter out. The column name is "content":

1. "Apple is my favourite fruit"
2. "Apple juice is delicious"
3. "Apple seeds are black"
4. "Apple juice is made from Apple"

I want to filter out the texts that include "Apple" but not "Apple juice" nor "Apple seed". Which means I want only `1` and `4` as the results.

I tried using the following query:

```
SELECT LOWER(content) 
FROM description 
where LOWER(content) like LOWER('%Apple%') 
    AND LOWER(content) NOT like LOWER('%Apple juice%') 
    AND LOWER(content) NOT like LOWER('%Apple seed%')
```

But it returns only `1`.

IDeally what would need to happen is to get the results of

```
SELECT LOWER(content) 
FROM description 
where LOWER(content) like LOWER('%Apple%')
```

And then remove the ones that include "Apple seed" or "Apple juice".

Comment: That's right.  2 & 4 contains "Apple Juice", 3 contains "apple seeds".  It's done exactly what you said you wanted.

Comment: There does not seem to be a question to answer, return only 1 meets the requirements (as expressed to this point)

Comment: 2 and 4 both contain "Apple juice", try another word to partially match 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter out the texts that include "Apple" but not "Apple juice" nor "Apple seed".

So if it has `apple`, don't show it (filter it out), but if it has `apple juice` or `apple seed` you can show it after all.

Try this:

```
where content not like '%Apple%'
    OR content like '%Apple juice%'
    OR content like '%Apple seed%'
```

Note I also removed all those `LOWER()` calls, as SQL is already case-insensitive by default. Generally this would also help with index use, but the leading wildcards mean this query is doomed for indexes anyway, and can never run fast.